# Can't retrieve data from the Same Servlet using request.getParameter() or request.getAttributes(), tried both get null only

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameters, attributes

I am sending **flag=update** to call update method with URL and also send the id of current record which user want to edit the record. Here my problem is I am unable to get parameters (fname, lname, email, pass, cno) values from the **edit method**. Every time it returns null from update method.

I think something wrong at update method or edit method. Please look into the matter. I want to understand why this problem occurs since I'm trying from last many hours.

I know that I can use `request.getAttributes();` instead of `request.getParameter();` to get data in the same servlet but let me know if their is any simple way or not? and please help to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

**Registration.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="Controller1" >

First Name : <input type="text" name="fName"><br/> 
Last Name : <input type="text" name="lName"><br/>
Email : <input type="text" name="eMail"><br/>
Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
Contact No : <input type="text" name="cNo"><br/><br/>

<input type="submit"  value="Register">
<input type="hidden" name="flag" value="register">

 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="Controller1?flag=login">Login</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="Controller1">

Email : <input type="text" name="lin_Email" value="insert your registered EmailID"><br/>
Password : <input type="text" name="lin_Pass" value="enter your registered password"><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Login">
<input type="hidden" name="flag" value="loginValidate">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Controller1.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Controller1
 */
@WebServlet("/Controller1")
public class Controller1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int id;
    String fname, lname, email, pass, cno, flag;
    PrintWriter out;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Controller1() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        flag = request.getParameter("flag");

        if (flag.equals("register")) {
            register(request, response);
        } else if (flag.equals("login")) {
            response.sendRedirect("/JDBC_Registration/Login.html");
        }

        else if (flag.equals("loginValidate")) {
            loginValidate(request, response);
        } else if (flag.equals("view")) {
            try {
                view(request, response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (flag.equals("edit")) {
            try {
                edit(request, response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (flag.equals("delete")) {
            delete(request, response);
        }
        else if (flag.equals("update")) {
            try {
                update(request, response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void update(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, SQLException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out = response.getWriter();

        id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
//
//      String fname = request.getParameter("t1");
//      String lname = request.getParameter("t2");
//      String email = request.getParameter("t3");
//      String pass = request.getParameter("t4");
//      String cno = request.getParameter("t5");

        fname = (String) request.getAttribute("t1");
        lname = (String) request.getAttribute("t2");
        email = (String) request.getAttribute("t3");
        pass = (String) request.getAttribute("t4");
        cno = (String) request.getAttribute("t5");
        System.out.println("updated values... "+fname+"  "+lname+" "+email+" "+pass+" "+cno);
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2","root","root");
            Statement stm = con.createStatement();

            stm.executeUpdate("update registration set FirstName='"+fname+"',LastName='"+lname+"',Email='"+email+"',Password='"+pass+"',ContactNo='"+cno+"' where id='"+id+"'");
            view(request, response);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void delete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out = response.getWriter();
        id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        System.out.println("delete record ID....."+id);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2","root","root");
            Statement stm = con.createStatement();

            stm.executeUpdate("delete from registration where id='"+id+"'");
            System.out.println("successfully deleted...record ID : "+id);
            view(request, response);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void edit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out = response.getWriter();
        id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        System.out.println(""+id);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2","root","root");
            Statement stm = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from registration where id='"+id+"'");

            out.println("<form action='Controller1'><table border=2>");
            out.println(
                    "<tr><td>ID</td><td>FirstName</td><td>LastName</td><td>Email</td><td>Password</td><td>ContactNo</td><td>Action</td></tr>");
            while (rs.next()) {
                out.println("<tr><td>" + rs.getString(1) + "</td><td><input type='text' name='t1' value=" + rs.getString(2) + "></td><td><input type='text' name='t2' value=" + rs.getString(3) + "></td><td><input type='text' name='t3' value=" + rs.getString(4) + "></td><td><input type='text' name='t4' value=" + rs.getString(5) + "></td><td><input type='text' name='t5' value=" + rs.getString(6) + "></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=Controller1?flag=update&id=" + rs.getString(1)
                        + ">Update</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>");
            }

            out.println("</table></form>");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void view(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2", "root", "root");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            // RequestDispatcher rd =
            // request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.html");
            // rd.include(request, response);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from registration");
            out.println("<form><table border=2>");
            out.println(
                    "<tr><td>ID</td><td>FirstName</td><td>LastName</td><td>Email</td><td>Password</td><td>ContactNo</td><td>Action</td></tr>");
            while (rs.next()) {
                out.println("<tr><td>" + rs.getString(1) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(3)
                        + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(4) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(5) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(6)
                        + "</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=Controller1?flag=edit&id=" + rs.getInt(1)
                        + ">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=Controller1?flag=delete&id=" + rs.getInt(1)
                        + ">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>");
            }

            out.println("</table></form>");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void loginValidate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            email = request.getParameter("lin_Email");
            pass = request.getParameter("lin_Pass");
            System.out.println("" + email + pass);

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2", "root", "root");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt
                    .executeQuery("select * from registration where Email='" + email + "'and Password='" + pass + "'");

            if (!rs.next()) {
                out.println("<h4 style='color:red'>Please Enter correct Email ID & Password...sq</h4><br/><br/>");
                // response.sendRedirect("/JDBC_Registration/Login.html");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.html");
                rd.include(request, response);
            } else {
                // System.out.println("else if called....");
                out.println("<h1>Welcome User :</h1><h3>" + rs.getString(2)
                        + "</h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=Controller1?flag=view>view</a>");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.html");
                rd.include(request, response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            fname = request.getParameter("fName");
            lname = request.getParameter("lName");
            email = request.getParameter("eMail");
            pass = request.getParameter("password");
            cno = request.getParameter("cNo");

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2", "root", "root");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into registration(FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,ContactNo) values('" + fname
                    + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + pass + "','" + cno + "')");
            System.out.println(" INSERT  : : : " + fname + " " + lname + " " + email + " " + pass + " " + cno);

            response.sendRedirect("/JDBC_Registration/Login.html");

            // view(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are using wrong parameter names in update? I mean they are called fName etc and you accessing t1, is it just for example, or it is so during execution? And also accessing attributes while they are actually parameters is wrong

Comment: It is applicable for execution. But when i tried it with Button instead of Hyperlink "Update" i got the parameters. so i think it's possible i'm doing mistake at sending the parameters with URL.

Comment: Please show us page from which update called

Comment: It is called from inside the same servlet. I'm not redirect it to another html form as i'm trying to learn the fundamentals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it worked for me when i put **submit button** instead of URL to call update method.

```
<input type='submit'>
<input type='hidden' name='flag' value='update'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='"+id+"'>
```

what happened here, Hyperlink value doesn't append with the remaining parameters t1,t2,t3,t4 & t5. By putting Submit button it takes all the parameter as consider as by default get() method.

Comment: @DmytroGrynets if suppose i want to pass parameter with the link "&" can be useful or not...for e.g. <a href=Controller1?flag=update&id='id'&t1='fname'&t2='lname'...........t5='cno'>

Comment: Yes, of course, but this way you would not be able to dynamically set those values without javascript

Comment: Ok. i got your point. thanks for the help. if you can give me an example of it that will be helpful for me to understand...or give me the referance link where it applied i'll look further. Thanks in advance!!@Dm

Comment: here is fiddle: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vcm0a8rj/1/), you can see that after submitting form all parameters are stored and sent, but when you click link, it just directly goes to url specified in href and not submitting form, if you want to add parameters to link dynamically, alongside submitting form, you can do [the following](https://jsfiddle.net/vcm0a8rj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have used a form in your jsp page. By default, it goes to the overridden doGet method. Here the function you've used is update(), So, try calling the getAttributes in the doGet method and pass it over to any other function of your choice.

Comment: It's not going there "by default" but rather depends on form's method. Also getting attributes from submitted form will result in nothing as it submits parameters, not attributes

Comment: I meant as he havent specified whether the form method is 'get' or 'post' it'll by default go to the doGet method.